# Github integration with git command line

Tags: command-line, git, github

In Vundle for vim, plugins are added with the following syntax:

```
Plugin 'user/repo'
```

This works for any github repository, and it makes for a very concise .vimrc.  My question is, is it possible to do this in the git command line.  I'd imagine the syntax would go a little something like this:

```
git clone user/repo
```

I tried googling around, but I haven't been able to find anything like this.

Use case for this feature might be if you remember the name of your own repository to clone on someone else's machine, but don't want to spend all the time typing the additional 23 characters to create form the https clone url.

If this doesn't exist, how might I go about writing my own program (Linux) to automatically do this?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has a command line tool called [hub](https://hub.github.com/) that has a command with exactly the syntax you've given.  From the [hub manual](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html):

> git clone [-p] OPTIONS [USER/]REPOSITORY DIRECTORY